# Vector of mutex to synchronize access to vector cells

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, mutex

I wrote code to do some parallel operations on a vector, my goal is to protect a single cell of a vector so other cells can be accessed in parallel, so I tried to use a vector of mutex of the same size of the other vector

```
vector<int> myIntVec(n,0);
vector<mutex> mtxVec(n);
```

then the critical section, each thread executes this (goal is to mark seen cells)

```
 for (i of something)
        {
           mtxVec[i].lock();
           if (myIntVec[i] == 0 ){ 
                myIntVec[i]++;
                mtxVec[i].unlock();
               }
            else
              mtxVec[i].unlock();
         }
```

no other operations on these 2 vectors.
but doing some tests, what i got is that myIntVec cells contain numbers greater than 1, when they should contain at least 1.
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean `myIntVec[i] == 0` ? `myIntVec` is a vector so it cannot be compared with 0.

Comment: sure, of course

Comment: Side note: either way the `if` goes, the last thing that happens is an unlock. That means the unlock can come out of the `if`, and if  you can do that, you can use a `unique_lock` or `scoped_lock` to get guaranteed unlocking.

Comment: How do you share the vectors between the threads? Is this done by reference?

Comment: actually there should be 2 other operations after the unlock in the if  case, nothing related to the vectors or concurrent so i preferred to leave them out of the lock to be done in parallel

Comment: @JérômeRichard yes lambda that captures everything by reference

Comment: For this trivial task a single scope-controlled lock-guarded mutex would work.

Comment: @WhozCraig could you explain more in detail ?

Comment: Yeah, I mean the expense of locking and unlocking a mutex *per cell* seems incredibly exorbitant, when, in reality, what you probably really care about is getting *any* cell that is "ready" (e.g. 0), bumping it, then taking action based on that state for that cell id. In short, the only protection you need is to find the first cell that is in the zero-state, accost it, then turn the mutex loose and let someone else have a crack at it. This should be doable  with a *single* mutex. I seriously doubt 10k elements with 10k mutexes is either desirable, nor practical, for example.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. From the code you posted it is not clear how you could get values larger than `1`.

Comment: @WhozCraig you mean a single mutex before any access to the vector? btw, i was trying to achieve that any other thread could access any other cell of the vector in parallel, except the 'locked' one.  But i'm really curious to understand why this solution is not working, what's wrong in principle?

Comment: nothing wrong in principle, most ppl would prefer : `unique_lock<mutex> l(vecMut[i]); if (vecInt[i]==0) vecInt[i]++;` in the loop, but that is just style. you should post a minimal but real example

Comment: and in some situations it might be ok to have high mutex count, it lowers contention, it depends if your access to each cell is long enough that it enables paralle work. For int in your simple example scenario maybe atomic<int> could suffice.

Comment: @user17732522 this is part of bigger context but this is the core part, the for loop iterates on a series of indices to go through, and the after unlock (in the if case) another 2 operations on variables internal to the thread. To debug i tried to print MyIntVec and i got cells with numbers like 2, 14, 7.. and i can't understand why.
I would like to understand  if that code is "logically" correct or not

Comment: In case you were wondering, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Pb8K8Mane) was what I was referring to earlier. Something like that anyway.

Comment: Currently there's no way to tell if the code is logically correct. The given snippet looks sound, but for all we know the program calls `overwrite_random_memory` immediately after.

Comment: @user4581301 i'm very glad to receive any other solution to the problem, besides this, my solution was based on the knowledge i have acquired about theory, so i wanted to know if it was "right" in principle and i had to investigate the problem in other ways or my theory knowledge was lacking.
..btw would     ` std::vector<std::atomic<int>>`  be atomic also in checking condition (v[i]==0) ?

Comment: The mutex is locked so the test is safe and the increment, if necessary, is safe. Then the mutex is unlocked. `std::atomic<int>` fails utterly here because the test for 0 and the increment are not one atomic transaction. You have the right idea. I'd write it differently ([See @YannTM 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933755/vector-of-mutex-to-synchronize-access-to-vector-cells?noredirect=1#comment125398310_70933755)), but there are a number of things that could be happening around this snippet to break the program as a whole. We need the [mre].

Comment: @user4581301 With [compare_exchance_strong](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange), test-and-increment is atomic just fine.

Comment: @user4581301  this is the best I could do https://codecollab.io/@proj/InternetDivisionTrucks# , it's heavily commented, hope it's enough. Executing it, seems to work fine, i got the expected and right result, but launching it hundreds of time (with same parameters) it gives a wrong result 2-3 times out of 100... so indicatin a synchronization problem i can't locate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order you share this link https://codecollab.io/@proj/InternetDivisionTrucks# in comments. Seems that you try to protect `vector<bool> visited(nn);` by mutexes `vector<mutex> vis_lock(nn);`. As i know there is special implementation for `std::vector<bool>` in which `bool`s stored packed https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool. so when it accesses to `i`-th element near elements also will be touched and with concurrency it's explodes because of accessing in one byte of memory at the same time. try replace `std::vector<bool>` to `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<int>`

Comment: well i think that's the right solution, for the first hundred of test seems vector<int> works fine. I'm going through another thousand of tests to be sure. Dang bool, i was going mad for that. Thank You